# Querying a oracle database from .Net with date parameters

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, .net-core

This one is destroying me....

I have an Oracle procedure as below: (this is my latest variation)

```
create or replace PROCEDURE MANAGEMENTFEES 
(
  STARTDATE IN VARCHAR2    
, ENDDATE IN VARCHAR2
, cursor_ OUT sys_refcursor
) AS 
BEGIN
OPEN cursor_ FOR
    select PR.PRNUM
    FROM MAXIMO.PR
    WHERE PR.ISSUEDATE > to_date(STARTDATE) AND PR.ISSUEDATE < to_date(ENDDATE) 
END MANAGEMENTFEES;
```

I am querying it using the following .Net code.

```
OracleConnection connection = getConnection();
            connection.Open();
            string startDate = new DateTime(2019, 1, 1).ToString("dd-MMM-yy");
            string endDate = new DateTime(2019, 5, 1).ToString("dd-MMM-yy");

            OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter();
            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
            cmd.Connection = connection;
            cmd.CommandText = "ORACLE.MANAGEMENTFEES";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("STARTDATE", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value =startDate;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("ENDDATE", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = endDate;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("cursor_", OracleDbType.RefCursor).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
```

This gives me a blank data table but it does have the headers.  SO that tells me the query just isnt getting any results.  I have been changing the date parameters using multiple stackoverflow answers but I am getting no where.

If I hard code the dates in the procedure it works fine but I want to be able to pass different dates in.

Help?

UPDATE - Added code in with hardcoded dates

```
create or replace PROCEDURE MANAGEMENTFEES 
(
  STARTDATE IN DATE    
, ENDDATE IN DATE
, cursor_ OUT sys_refcursor
) AS 
BEGIN
OPEN cursor_ FOR
    select PR.PRNUM
    FROM MAXIMO.PR
    WHERE PR.ISSUEDATE > '01-JAN-19' AND PR.ISSUEDATE < '01-MAY-19' 
    ORDER BY ISSUEDATE ASC;
END MANAGEMENTFEES;
```

Comment: Why the dates are strings? Fix this.

Comment: If they *are* strings, then try to apply correct format mask to `to_date`, e.g. `to_date(STARTDATE, 'mm/dd/yyyy)`

Comment: When you use `to_date()` you need to pass in both the string **and** the format mask describing the format of the string-as-a-date. But as sticky bit has said, pass your dates in as dates.

Comment: Again you compare a string with a DATE - stick to `DATE` values! I.e. `WHERE PR.ISSUEDATE > DATE '1999-01-0' AND PR.ISSUEDATE < DATE '1999-05-01'` (or `DATE '2099-01-01'` and `DATE '2099-05-01'` ?)

Comment: This was just an example of using the dates hardcoded based on your query below your answer.

Comment: Yes, but wrong examples. Use DATE literals, e.g. `DATE '1999-01-01'` (sorry for the typo above) or TO_DATE function, e.g. `TO_DATE('01-JAN-19', 'DD-MON-RR', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = AMERICAN')`

Comment: Hi  if I do to_date('01-JAN-19') and same for enddate in the sql statement and execute from .net app it returns data.  It must be how it is converting the date between .net and oracle

Comment: You should **never** use `TO_DATE()` without the datetime model format, it is even so documented in [TO_DATE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions219.htm#SQLRF06132). If you skip it then Oracle defaults it from the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter which can be different for every session and may change at any time.

Answer (score 1):

Your procedure should be like this:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE MANAGEMENTFEES 
(
  STARTDATE IN DATE
, ENDDATE IN DATE
, cursor_ OUT sys_refcursor
) AS 
BEGIN
OPEN cursor_ FOR
    select PR.PRNUM
    FROM MAXIMO.PR
    WHERE PR.ISSUEDATE > STARTDATE AND PR.ISSUEDATE < ENDDATE
END MANAGEMENTFEES;
```

and the call in .NET would be this:

```
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2019, 1, 1);
DateTime endDate = new DateTime(2019, 5, 1);
...
cmd.Parameters.Add("STARTDATE", OracleDbType.Date).Value = startDate;
cmd.Parameters.Add("ENDDATE", OracleDbType.Date).Value = endDate;
```

Comment: that is what I have had orginally, doesnt return anything apart from the headers.  If I amend the SP to use 01-May-19 and 01-JAN-19 as hardcoded values I get a result.

Comment: Maybe try `>=` and/or `<=`. Does `ISSUEDATE` have a time value, i.e. is the time value different to `00:00:00`

Comment: adding = doesnt help and the ISSUEDATE is type DATE in the oracle DB and doesnt have a time

Comment: What is the data type of column `ISSUEDATE`?

Comment: the data type is DATE

Comment: What happens if you query directly? How does your statement looks like in this case?

Comment: I have edited my question to include.  I have tested this from my .net app and it returns results.

Answer (score 0):

This is now resolved and it was caused by the use of `STARTDATE` and `ENDDATE` which are reserved by Oracle (although no error was thrown).

Changing them to `v_STARTDATE` and `v_ENDDATE` resolved the issue.